# Difference between SetProperty and RemoveChild in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, removechild, vbox

I am new to Flex. Recently, I am learning about 'state' concept in Flex.

When state is changed, we can define the new properties for the new state overidding the properties of the base state.

But, I had a doubt.
**What is the difference between using setProperty() and removeChild() in Flex ?**

Take the following case.
Suppose there are 2 Vbox inside the application container. When the state is changed by some event, I need only 1 VBox in the appln container.

> (a) Should I set setProperty for that particular VBox of width and
>   height to 0 ?  or
>    (b)   Should I remove the
>   VBox from the new state by using
>   removeChild() property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different.
SetProperty means changing some properties of the instance, you can set any property that you can access in the context. In case you need to re-use the VBox in future (i think this is your case), you should utilize this function. Normally, don't set **width** and **height** to 0 (some components has **minimumWidth** and **minimumHeight** that can break your logic). Instead, set its **visible** to **false** and **includeInLayout** to **false** too.

You only use **removeChild** when you no longer need that VBox. Otherwise, when you need to **addChild** it into your layout, you have to rearrange the order of the component's children.